# VB 2012 IP block

Tags: vb.net, ip, block, monitor

I am using VB 2012 and am wondering if there is a way to monitor the IP addresses all programs on the system access, and then compare them to a database of disallowed IPs. If they match, the program will block access to that IP. Is there some code examples on how to detect accessed IPs and block them?

Comment: what do you mean *monitor the IP addresses all programs*?

Comment: @TaylorFlores monitoring the IP addresses all programs are accessing, such as a TCP viewer does.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Got any ideas?

Comment: Not for VB, someone else probably does though. This may help you, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx. I'm more of a C/Linux person

Answer (score 0):

Netstat - Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.  Using the process class, you can run it without a window and control it's standard in and out.

Alternatively, if you have a router with a web interface, you could query it to supply that info.

Comment: Can you give a general idea on how to implement netstat with vb?

Comment: oops forgot to add the link here it is, [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).